# Generate a log from all commits I've done in a day (or in an specific date) using CVS (log or history)?

Tags: version-control, command-line, cvs, cmd, commit

I have to use CVS in my work and at the end of the day, I need to generate a report in an internal enterprise system.

I write meaningful comments in all my work. I would like to do a `cvs log` or `cvs history`, with only the comments from each file I have commited to the repository (a solution using only command line, so I could automate other actions). How do I do it?

Comment: I don't suppose you have Bonsai do you? That makes it easy.

Comment: Hum, I'm interested in doing it command line, so I could pipe it do xsel and paste inside my internal enterprise system. Thanks for the suggestion tough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[cvs2cl](http://www.red-bean.com/cvs2cl/) is what I'm going to use. I'm going to use it with sed and other utilities. It's a great application!